# React Router: What's the purpose of Browser History? Is Browser History mandatory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is the Browser History just for to change between already visited pages for and back?

But browsers have these ability already. Why is another module needed?

Moreover:

I have tried React Router **without** Browser History. React Router kept working. I could get all the single components via entering the corresponding URL into the adressbar.

What consequences does it have when I use React Router **without** Browser History?

Comment: Are you able to go back and forth in the history without using it?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it another time: Removed the " history={ History } " attribute. Restarted the web server. Clicked links to different pages. Afterward I could use the back-button of Chrome and it show the pages I visited at last, second last etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your server config to be a SPA application like this :

```
NODE server
 // serve static assets normally
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

 // handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
 // a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
  app.get('*', function (request, response){
   response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
  })
```

Without `browserHistory`, when you navigate to other URL except `/` like `/posts/1` and refresh the page. The server only gives you the home page. With `browserHistory`, the router will handle those `URL` properly. For more information, read the [doc](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory)